# Duplo evento no click jQuery

Tags: jquery, click

Estou a tempo tendo problemas nos eventos do jQuery. Já utilizei de todas as práticas recomendadas para barrar o duplo evento de *click*. Segue exemplos:

```
.off()
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
unbid('click');
```

Sempre quando tem um click eu efetuo essa função

```
function LoadingTela(botao,tipo) {
     if (tipo == true) {
       $(botao).prop("disabled", true); 
       $('.mask-loading').show(); 
     }else { 
       $(botao).prop("disabled", false); 
       $('.mask-loading').hide(); 
     } 
 }
```

Alguém chegou a alguma solução ou novo controle de evento?

Comment: Parece que seu evento está sendo chamado duas vezes, o **.off** vc disse que usou, foi na hora de criar o evento? Por exemplo, tente fazer **$("#botao").off("click").on("click",function(){ /*suas coisas aqui*/ });** para evitar que ele seja criado duas ou mais vezes. Caso isso não funcione você pode tentar algo mais complexo, algo como salvar no seu botão quando ele for clicado e só permitir clicks novamente depois de, digamos, 1 segundo. Se precisar posso te montar um exemplo.

Comment: `function LoadingTela(botao,tipo) {
    if (tipo == true) {
        $(botao).prop("disabled", true);
        $('.mask-loading').show();
    } else {
        $(botao).prop("disabled", false);
        $('.mask-loading').hide();
    }        
}`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar com a função `one` do jQuery. Ela é semelhante à função `on`, com a diferença que o evento é removido do elemento apenas sua primeira execução, ou seja, para o exemplo abaixo a função no evento `click` será executada apenas uma vez.

```js
$('#btn').one('click', event => {
  console.log('Botão pressionado');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Pressione-me!</button>
```

Se for possível que o evento seja disparado múltiplas vezes na mesma página e a intenção seja somente proteger de múltiplos cliques *simultâneos*, você pode desabilitar o botão (ou elemento que dispara o evento) enquanto estiver processando a aplicação:

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function(event) {
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
  console.log('Botão pressionado');
  
  // processando o evento click...
  
  $(this).prop('disabled', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Pressione-me!</button>
```

Comment: Porem este botão sera executado novamente na mesma tela, pela aplicação  estar baseada em ajax, tem como renovar este btn sem atualizar a pagina ?

Comment: Utilizei esse controle de desabilitar o botão mais sempre no segundo click a minha function que esta sendo chamada duas vezes, pode ter ficado algum resquício do evento na pagina para ele ser disparado duas vezes ?

Comment: @Guilhermezio consegue fazer um [mcve]?

Comment: Utilizo sempre quando clico essa função                                 
  `function LoadingTela(botao,tipo) {
    if (tipo == true) {
        $(botao).prop("disabled", true);
        $('.mask-loading').show();
    } else {
        $(botao).prop("disabled", false);
        $('.mask-loading').hide();
    }        
}`

Comment: editado a pergunta com o exemplo